# flask-sqlalchemy "no such table" under mod_wsgi

Tags: python, sqlite, flask, sqlalchemy, mod-wsgi

For some reason flask-sqlalchemy seems to have problems resolving the sqlite tables when running under apache + mod_wsgi.

simplified example:

```
from models import db, User

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['DEBUG'] = True
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:////tmp/zop.sqlite3'
db.init_app(app)
```

models.py:

```
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
db = SQLAlchemy()

class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(50), unique=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True)
    ...
```

Basically my app works fine when I run it via `python myapp.py`

But when I run this under apache + mod_wsgi, I get the following error when I run something like `User.query.filter_by(name=username).first()`:

```
OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such table: user [SQL: u'SELECT user.id AS user_id, user.name AS user_name, user.email AS user_email \\nFROM user \\nWHERE user.name = ?\\n LIMIT ? OFFSET ?'] [parameters: ('foo', 1, 0)]
```

Is there anything I need to change to get it working under apache+mod_wsgi?

Comment: Did you create tables with `db.create_all()`?

Comment: Did you check the permissions on the sqlite db file? If Apache didn't create it, make sure Apache has permission to read it.

Comment: Yes - tables created with db.create_all() [ note that python myapp.py works ]

Comment: Also changed perms on the sqlite file to be 777 - to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK - figured it out. Leaving the answer here in case someone else gets bitten by this. It turns out that Apache on newer redhat based systems (specifically ones that use systemd) uses a private /tmp.

This is specified in `/usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service`

```
[Service]
PrivateTmp=true
```

Because of this, my DB was in `/tmp/systemd-private-M4Xj0e/tmp/zop.sqlite3` rather than `/tmp/zop.sqlite3`. And this DB in the private tmp directory was never properly initialized - running `db.create_all()` was only creating `/tmp/zop.sqlite3` but not `/tmp/systemd-private-M4Xj0e/tmp/zop.sqlite3`. Apache was throwing errors because it couldn't find the DB.

Using an alternate non-tmp DB location (eg. `/var/www/zop.sqlite3`) or setting `PrivateTmp=false` fixes this

More here: http://blog.oddbit.com/2012/11/05/fedora-private-tmp/